# Sorting and opening and writing a file

Tags: python, file, sorting

I am trying to write a function that do the following

- Open the file word_list.txt
- Read the contents of this file into a list
- Sort the list in alphabetical order
- Write the contents of the list to a file called alphabetic.txt

This is my code

```
def alphabetic():
    file = open("word-text.txt","r")
    data=file.read()
    print (data)
    file.close()
    listsort=data
    listsort.sort()
    print(listsort)
```

Whenever I try to run this code, the list that I used "file" won't be sorted and I get the following results (which is the same list order that I have) and I am trying to sort them with alphabetical order with an error

```
>>> alphabetic()
apples
oranges
watermelon
kiwi
zucchini
carrot
okra
jalapeno
pepper
cucumber
banana
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#32>", line 1, in <module>
    alphabetic()
  File "/Users/user/Desk`enter code here`top/Outlook(1)/lab6.py", line 15, in alphabetic
    listsort.sort()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sort'`
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. I have removed some of the tags you added as probably irrelevant. You should update the tags with a language tag — which is probably Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach wasn't working because the `read` method  returns only a string. Since Python strings don't have a `sort()` method, you got the error that you did. The `sort` method applies to `lists` as shown in my approach using the `readlines` method.

If this is your file's contents:

```
apples
oranges
watermelon
kiwi
zucchini
carrot
okra
jalapeno
pepper
cucumber
banana
```

Here's the associated code:

```
with open('word-text.txt', 'r') as f:
    words = f.readlines()

    #Strip the words of the newline characters (you may or may not want to do this):
    words = [word.strip() for word in words]

    #sort the list:
    words.sort()
    print words
```

This outputs:

```
['apples', 'banana', 'carrot', 'cucumber', 'jalapeno', 'kiwi', 'okra', 'oranges', 'pepper', 'watermelon', 'zucchini']
```

Comment: @user2924427: if my answer was useful to you, then please consider it for acceptance. :)